# A human convict ex military transformes into an alien!

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short science fiction story (like The Outer Limits). It's about a convict (ex military) who has the choice between death or being injected with some alien virus.

He is slowly transformed into an alien. When the transformation is complete, the humans want to kill him. He escapes, while they (humans) send a unit after him. He doesn't kill any of them. In the end, they catch him, but before they can kill him the aliens come to his rescue.

One of the humans or aliens said,

> They are not ready yet!

Comment: Can you remember the year? Can you remember if this was a movie, a written story or an episode of a scifi TV series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you might be thinking of the Outer Limits episode *The Afterlife*.  Included below are the IMDB and Wiki Descriptions along with a link to the actual episode on Hulu.

Stiles is a man wrongly convicted of murdering eleven people. He is offered a choice between execution and cooperating with an experiment. His religious beliefs don't allow him to choose execution, which would amount to suicide, so he is forced into participating in a genetic experiment to splice his genes with extraterrestrial DNA.

> As a result Stiles changes into what appears to be a horrific monster with enhanced senses and mental capacity. His captors allow him to escape so that they may hunt him down. When the end comes near for Stiles, the tables turn as aliens resembling the now completely mutated Stiles appear. The aliens and Stiles beam away, leaving his pursuers to realize that they were being tested by the aliens and that they had failed the test.

[IMDB Outer Limits - Afterlife](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667859/)

[Wiki Outer Limits - Afterlife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterlife_%28The_Outer_Limits%29)

[Hulu Episode](http://www.hulu.com/watch/4496#i0,p32,d0)

Comment: Yes that is it , thanks

Comment: @Bigben59.  GREAT!  I'm glad I could help find this.  If you could flag it as the correct answer, that would be appreciated.   Thanks.

Comment: @Bigben59.  Just wanted to touch base.  Would it be possible for you to mark this as the correct answer please?  Thank you.